# How to add new currency

Tags: virtocommerce

If I want to add a new currency how I can add in my virtocommerce? is their any option to add new currency or I should try it to add in Currency table?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new currency by going to pricing->pricelists->select a price->click edit next to currency label and their you can add a new currency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively by this path Stores-> click pen near currencies fields
[image]

Or in modules
[image]